# MVC sign out of claims identity authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

Moving away from Forms Authentication and trying to get my head around Claims Identity users can successfully login using this

```
Dim vIdentity As New ClaimsIdentity({New Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Session("UserName"))}, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role)
                vIdentity.AddClaim(New Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"))
                Authentication.SignIn(New AuthenticationProperties With {.IsPersistent = False}, vIdentity)
```

But having problems with the logout - I thought AuthenticationManager.Signout() would work but I get 'Signout is not a member of AuthenticationManager' so now a little stumped.

This is in Global

```
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name
```

I tried this in the logout controller

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
        If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            Dim vUser = TryCast(User, ClaimsPrincipal)
            Dim vIdentity = TryCast(User.Identity, ClaimsIdentity)
            Dim vClaim = (From c In vUser.Claims Where c.Value = Session("UserName") Select c).Single()
            vIdentity.RemoveClaim(vClaim)
        End If
        Return View()
    End Function
```

But that returned the error

```
A claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity.
```

when it hit

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spotted it - defined the user as a role and a name in global - changed it to

```
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role
```

Never ceases to amaze me that I can bang my head for hours over something and as soon as I post the question............